# not able to scan the string with spaces

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

https://www.codechef.com/problems/LADDU
not able to scan string in the array "work" on line 12 of the code.

```
     #include<stdio.h>

     int main()
     {
        long long int i,j,T,actv,points,a,b,c;
        char origin[100],work[100];
        scanf("%lld",&T);
        while(T--)
        {
            points=0;
            scanf("%lld %s",&actv,origin);
            for(i=0;i<actv;i++)
            {
                    printf("hie\n");
                    scanf("%[^\n]s",work);
                    printf("hello\n");
            }
       }

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",work);` --> `scanf(" %99[^\n]%*c", work);`

Comment: speed is a strong consideration for this codechef problem.  (<1second)  The output is a single number (for each test case) followed by a newline (and a newline at the end of the program.   The posted code 1) does not implement the problem set. 2) does not output the correct value nor the correct format. 3) does not allow for the different 'activities' 4) there are no negative values involved, so all variables can be `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: per the problem set, there are NO strings with spaces to be input.

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both).

Comment: do not use tabs for indenting.  Because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with a variable width font.   Strongly suggest: do not omit the optional braces '{' and '}' as they make the code much easier to read/understand and minimize certain kinds of format errors when performing future editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `scanf()` use `fgets()` to scan a string with spaces.

```
fgets(work,sizeof(work),stdin);
```

Note:
`fgets()` comes with a newline character. So

```
size_t n = strlen(work);
if(n>0 && work[n-1] == '\n')
{
   work[n-1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead of scanf.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE sizeof(work)

if (fgets(work, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) != NULL)
{
   // your stuff
}
```

To get your string with spaces.

If your C-stirng is shorter than `BUFFERSIZE` last char before null terminator will be '`\n'`

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%lld %s",&actv,origin);`

After the line is executed, newline remains unconsumed.

`scanf("%[^\n]s",work);`

Since `%[^\n]`doesn't accept the newline, it doesn't perform read.
(Also, `s` is not required. E.g. `%[^\n]s` --> `%[^\n]`)

So, Change such in the following.

`scanf("%lld %s%*c",&actv,origin);`//`%*c` for skip one character(newline) or `while(getchar()!='\n');`//skip upto newline
...
`scanf("%99[^\n]%*c",work);`

Answer (score 0):

for fast reading/writing of numbers use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fastRead( size_t *a );
void fastWrite( size_t a );

inline void fastRead(size_t *a)
{
    int c=0;
    // note: 32 is space character
    // consume leading trash
    while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();

    // initialize result value
    *a=0;

    // punctuation parens, etc are show stoppers
    while (c>47 && c <58)
    { // then in range 0...9
        *a = (*a)*10 + (size_t)(c-48);
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    //printf( "%s, value: %lu\n", __func__, *a );
} // end function: fastRead


inline void fastWrite(size_t a)
{
    char snum[20];
    //printf( "%s, %lu\n", __func__, a );

    int i=0;
    // decompose 'a' into char array
    do
    {
        // 48 is numeric character 0
        snum[i++] = (char)((a%10)+(size_t)48);
        a=a/10;
    }while(a>0);

    i=i-1; // correction for overincrement from prior 'while' loop

    while(i>=0)
    {
        putchar_unlocked(snum[i--]);
    }
    putchar_unlocked('\n');
} // end function: fastWrite
```

Along with the above two functions, here is a typical program using those functions:

```
#define MAX_VALUE (1000000)

int array[ MAX_VALUE +1 ];

int main( void )
{
    // get number of test cases
    size_t  numTestCases;
    fastRead( &numTestCase );
    //scanf( "%lu", &numTestCases );
    //printf( "%s, Number of Test Cases: %lu\n", __func__, numTestCases);

    // accumulate test cases, sorted
    for( size_t i=0; i<numTestCases; i++ )
    {
        size_t value;
        fastRead( &value );
        //scanf( "%lu", &value );
        array[value]++;
    }

    // output the unique values, assending
    for( size_t i=0; i<MAX_VALUE; i++ )
    {
        if( array[i] )
        {
            fastWrite( i );
            //printf( "%s. %lu\n", __func__, i );
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The fastRead and fastWrite functions (rather than printf and scanf) will greatly speed up your code.

Now you only need to implement the problem set.

Note: to read in a string:

```
size_t i = 0;
while( i < sizeof( inputArray ) && (ch = getchar_unlocked()) && ' ' != ch )
{
    inputArray[i] = ch;
    i++;
}
inputArray[i] = '\0';
```

You could use some other string delimiter, like a '\n', rather than ' '